# Edge browser: Events stop working, when any browser control is clicked

Tags: microsoft-edge, browser-extension, microsoft-edge-extension

My extension for the Edge browser adds some mouse and keyboard events to the current page. The extension is launched from the browser action element.

The problem is that when the browser action element is clicked, the current window loses its focus, and the events stop firing, until the page is focused back by mouse clicking any page area.

I setup my event handlers like that:

```
wrapper.addEventListener('keydown', onKeyDown, true);
wrapper.addEventListener('mousemove', selectElementMouseMove, true);
```

I tried window.focus(), document.body.focus(), chrome.tabs.update, chrome.window.update - they do not help.

The focus is also lost, when I click any element of the browser outside of the web page area.

Is there any way to prevent this behaviour?